Click event doesn't happen until I click the button 2-3 times
I am writing a calculator for ADHD medication dosages. However, when I press "Convert!" I have to click it several times for the placeholder text to appear. What's going on? Nothing I try seems to work but to be completely honest I have no idea what to do in this situation - please advise.
I tried changing onclick in the HTML tag to am event listener in JS but it has not helped.


function convertRitalinLA() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 10mg."
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 20mg."
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 30mg."
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 40mg."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 60mg."
      } else if (toTheseMedictions === "Concerta") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("36mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 36mg."
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("72mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 72mg."
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("108mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 108mg"
        } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
          console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
        }
      } else if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("5mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 5mg."
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("10mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 10mg."
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("15mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 15mg."
        } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
          console.log("20mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 0mg."
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("30mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
        }
      } else if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("20mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("30mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("40mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
        } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
          console.log("60mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("70mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    console.log("Error.")
    placeholder.innerHTML = "Error."
  }
}

function convertRitalin() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Ritalin") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "46mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("8mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "80mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("100mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "100mg"
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("18mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "18mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("36mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "36mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("72mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "72mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("108mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "108mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("5mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("38mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "38mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("50mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("70mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
  }
}

function convertDexamfetamine() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.value = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.value = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
      }
    }
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("80mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "80mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("100mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "100mg"
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("120mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "120mg"
      }
    }

    if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("36mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "36mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("72mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "72mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("108mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "108mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
    if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("50mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("70mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
  }
}


function convertConcerta() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Concerta") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages == "18mg") {
        console.log("5mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
      } else if (dosages == "36mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages == "54mg") {
        console.log("15mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
      }
      if (dosages == "72mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      }
      if (dosages == "108mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      }
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    if (dosages == "18mg") {
      console.log("10mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
    } else if (dosages == "36mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages == "54mg") {
      console.log("30mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
    } else if (dosages == "72mg") {
      console.log("40mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
    } else if (dosages == "108mg") {
      console.log("50mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
    if (dosages === "18mg") {
      console.log("5mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
    } else if (dosages === "36mg") {
      console.log("10mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
    } else if (dosages === "54mg") {
      console.log("15mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
    } else if (dosages === "72mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages === "108mg") {
      console.log("25mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "25mg"
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
    if (dosages === "18mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages === "36mg") {
      console.log("30mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
    } else if (dosages === "54mg") {
      console.log("40mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
    } else if (dosages === "72mg") {
      console.log("50mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
    } else if (dosages === "108mg") {
      console.log("70mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
    }
  }
}

function concvertVyvanse() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Vyvanse") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosage === "20mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
      } else if (dosage === "30mg") {
        console.log("15mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
      } else if (dosage === "40mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosage === "50mg") {
        console.log("25mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "25mg"
      } else if (dosage === "60mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosage === "70mg") {
        console.log("35mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "35mg"
      }
    }
  }
}


function init() {

  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Ritalin LA") {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = convertRitalinLA;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Ritalin") {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = convertRitalin;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Dexamfetamine") {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = convertDexamfetamine;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Concerta") {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = convertConcerta;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Vyvanse") {
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = convertVyvanse;
    }
  }

}

window.onload = init;
<div id="header">
  <img src="flag.png" alt="Australian flag." width="150" height="75">
  <h1>The Australian ADHD Medication Calculator</h1>
  <p>This calculator will only convert medications that are available for sale in Austraia. Unlike other, US based calculators, you won't have to scroll through a whole list of medications with strange names. Also, you using this calculator means a lot to
    its (Aussie) creator!
  </p>
</div>
<div id="convert">
  <h3>I want to convert...</h3>
  <form id="medications">
    <label for="convertMedications"></label>
    <select name="convertMedications" id="convertMedications">
      <option value="Ritalin">Ritalin</option>
      <option value="Ritalin LA">Ritalin LA</option>
      <option value="Concerta">Concerta</option>
      <option value="Dexamfetamine">Dexamfetamine</option>
      <option value="Vyvanse">Vyvanse</option>
    </select>
    <label for="dosages"></label>
    <select name="dosages" id="dosages">
      <option value="5mg">5mg</option>
      <option value="10mg">10mg</option>
      <option value="18mg">18mg</option>
      <option value="20mg">20mg</option>
      <option value="27mg">27mg</option>
      <option value="30mg">30mg</option>
      <option value="36mg">36mg</option>
      <option value="40mg">40mg</option>
      <option value="50mg">50mg</option>
      <option value="54mg">54mg</option>
      <option value="60mg">60mg</option>
      <option value="70mg">70mg</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="toThese">
  <h3>to</h3>
  <form>
    <label for="toTheseMedications"></label>
    <select name="toTheseMedications" id="toTheseMedications">
      <option value="Ritalin">Ritalin</option>
      <option value="Ritalin LA">Ritalin LA</option>
      <option value="Concerta">Concerta</option>
      <option value="Dexamfetamine">Dexamfetamine</option>
      <option value="Vyvanse">Vyvanse</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick=init()>Convert!</button>
  </form>
  <p id="placeholder"></p>
</div>




Just follow the code flow for your button.

Click 1 calls init()
init() sets up event handler to call myFunction()
Click 2 calls myFunction()
myFunction() sets up event handler to call one of your convertXXX() functions
Click 3 calls the specific convertXXX() function

So;
Let's get rid of the init() "wrapper" function, leaving just myFunction()
Change myFunction() so that it calls each convertXXX() function directly.
Get rid of the window.onload = init; line
Change the html for button to set onclick="myFunction()"
Also, you have toTheseMedications spelled wrong in one spot:

} else if (toTheseMedictions === "Concerta") {

should be

} else if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {

That leaves us with the working code in this code snippet:
NOTE: Make sure you test it with dosages that you have coded for. For example, if you try converting 5mg of Ritlan LA, nothing will happen.


function convertRitalinLA() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 10mg."
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 20mg."
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 30mg."
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 40mg."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Ritalin is 60mg."
      } else if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("36mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 36mg."
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("72mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 72mg."
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("108mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 108mg"
        } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
          console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
        }
      } else if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("5mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 5mg."
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("10mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 10mg."
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("15mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 15mg."
        } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
          console.log("20mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "Your new dose of Concerta is 0mg."
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("30mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
        }
      } else if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
        if (dosages = "10mg") {
          console.log("20mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
        } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
          console.log("30mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
        } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
          console.log("40mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
        } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
          console.log("60mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
        } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
          console.log("70mg")
          placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    console.log("Error.")
    placeholder.innerHTML = "Error."
  }
}

function convertRitalin() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Ritalin") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "46mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("8mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "80mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("100mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "100mg"
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("18mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "18mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("36mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "36mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("72mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "72mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("108mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "108mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("5mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("38mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "38mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      }
    } else if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
      if (dosages === "5mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("50mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("70mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
  }
}

function convertDexamfetamine() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.value = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.value = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
      }
    }
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("40mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("60mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "60mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("80mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "80mg"
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("100mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "100mg"
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("120mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "120mg"
      }
    }

    if (toTheseMedications === "Concerta") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("36mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "36mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("72mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "72mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("108mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "108mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
    if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
      if (dosages === "10mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosages === "20mg") {
        console.log("50mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
      } else if (dosages === "30mg") {
        console.log("70mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
      } else if (dosages === "40mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "50mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      } else if (dosages === "60mg") {
        console.log("Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose.")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Warning! Dose exceeds maximum daily dose."
      }
    }
  }
}


function convertConcerta() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Concerta") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosages == "18mg") {
        console.log("5mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
      } else if (dosages == "36mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
      } else if (dosages == "54mg") {
        console.log("15mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
      }
      if (dosages == "72mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
      }
      if (dosages == "108mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
      }
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin LA") {
    if (dosages == "18mg") {
      console.log("10mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
    } else if (dosages == "36mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages == "54mg") {
      console.log("30mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
    } else if (dosages == "72mg") {
      console.log("40mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
    } else if (dosages == "108mg") {
      console.log("50mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Dexamfetamine") {
    if (dosages === "18mg") {
      console.log("5mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "5mg"
    } else if (dosages === "36mg") {
      console.log("10mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "10mg"
    } else if (dosages === "54mg") {
      console.log("15mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
    } else if (dosages === "72mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages === "108mg") {
      console.log("25mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "25mg"
    }
  }

  if (toTheseMedications === "Vyvanse") {
    if (dosages === "18mg") {
      console.log("20mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "20mg"
    } else if (dosages === "36mg") {
      console.log("30mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "30mg"
    } else if (dosages === "54mg") {
      console.log("40mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "40mg"
    } else if (dosages === "72mg") {
      console.log("50mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "50mg"
    } else if (dosages === "108mg") {
      console.log("70mg")
      placeholder.innerHTML = "70mg"
    }
  }
}

function concvertVyvanse() {
  var convertMedications = document.getElementById("convertMedications").value;
  var dosages = document.getElementById("dosages").value;
  var toTheseMedications = document.getElementById("toTheseMedications").value;
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

  if (convertMedications === "Vyvanse") {
    if (toTheseMedications === "Ritalin") {
      if (dosage === "20mg") {
        console.log("10mg")
      } else if (dosage === "30mg") {
        console.log("15mg")
        placeholder.innerHTML = "15mg"
      } else if (dosage === "40mg") {
        console.log("20mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "20mg"
      } else if (dosage === "50mg") {
        console.log("25mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "25mg"
      } else if (dosage === "60mg") {
        console.log("30mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "30mg"
      } else if (dosage === "70mg") {
        console.log("35mg")
        placeholder.innerHML = "35mg"
      }
    }
  }
}


function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Ritalin LA") {
    convertRitalinLA();
  }
  if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Ritalin") {
    convertRitalin();
  }
  if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Dexamfetamine") {
    convertDexamfetamine();
  }
  if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Concerta") {
    convertConcerta();
  }
  if (document.getElementById("convertMedications").value === "Vyvanse") {
    convertVyvanse();
  }
}
<div id="header">
  <img src="flag.png" alt="Australian flag." width="150" height="75">
  <h1>The Australian ADHD Medication Calculator</h1>
  <p>This calculator will only convert medications that are available for sale in Austraia. Unlike other, US based calculators, you won't have to scroll through a whole list of medications with strange names. Also, you using this calculator means a lot to
    its (Aussie) creator!
  </p>
</div>
<div id="convert">
  <h3>I want to convert...</h3>
  <form id="medications">
    <label for="convertMedications"></label>
    <select name="convertMedications" id="convertMedications">
      <option value="Ritalin">Ritalin</option>
      <option value="Ritalin LA">Ritalin LA</option>
      <option value="Concerta">Concerta</option>
      <option value="Dexamfetamine">Dexamfetamine</option>
      <option value="Vyvanse">Vyvanse</option>
    </select>
    <label for="dosages"></label>
    <select name="dosages" id="dosages">
      <option value="5mg">5mg</option>
      <option value="10mg">10mg</option>
      <option value="18mg">18mg</option>
      <option value="20mg">20mg</option>
      <option value="27mg">27mg</option>
      <option value="30mg">30mg</option>
      <option value="36mg">36mg</option>
      <option value="40mg">40mg</option>
      <option value="50mg">50mg</option>
      <option value="54mg">54mg</option>
      <option value="60mg">60mg</option>
      <option value="70mg">70mg</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="toThese">
  <h3>to</h3>
  <form>
    <label for="toTheseMedications"></label>
    <select name="toTheseMedications" id="toTheseMedications">
      <option value="Ritalin">Ritalin</option>
      <option value="Ritalin LA">Ritalin LA</option>
      <option value="Concerta">Concerta</option>
      <option value="Dexamfetamine">Dexamfetamine</option>
      <option value="Vyvanse">Vyvanse</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Convert!</button>
  </form>
  <p id="placeholder"></p>
</div>



